# Merge wires to fit into spotlight

Tags: electrical, wiring, recessed-lighting, uk

I'm changing a ceiling bulb into a spotlight and ran into a problem. I have 3 neutral wires, but my spotlight only has 2 holes. I tried putting the wires in together, but there's not enough space to properly fit both. You can see them on the left side of the image:

[image]

I went to my local shop and I bought a connector and another wire. My plan is to merge the 2 wires using the connector (it has a wider hole) and use the other wire to connect to the spotlight. But now I noticed that the wire I bought is not exactly the same as the wires that come out of the ceiling (the others are thicker) and I am not sure if that is a problem. Does this approach make sense or do I need to buy a different wire/connector?

[image]

Comment: I think you are not from the US and will have laws etc different then here. I would use a device called a "Wire Nut" or scotch lock, it would require less space and no tape.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That sounds like a good plan, the lamp will not need the same thickness of wire as the rest of the circuit so the slightly thinner wire will be fine.

You should probably be using a  junction box and then three wires from there to your spotlight.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the top part of the picture, someone had the same problem there, and solved it by using a larger connector block to take the two thicker wires down to one thinner one. You could do the same, taking just one neutral wire into the fitting. I guess this is U.K., and a 1mm blue wire will suffice.